# C# directory.create with physical path

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a directory with directory.create() passing the physical path (and not the relative with Server.MapPath...)

```
new FileInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerPath"].ToString() + "/" + file.Id).Directory.Create();
```

Web.config:

```
<add key="ServerPath" value="C:/inetpub/wwwroot"/>
```

But its not working. Any ideas?
I am trying to copy a file to this directory and I get back this error:

> Copy failed:Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/103/filename.png'. OK

Because the folder /103 is not created under C:/inetpub/wwwroot.
Elevated privileges are ok.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What error do you get?

Comment: After this line I am trying to copy a file to this direction and I get an error that part of this directory doesn't exist

Comment: Is the directory created?

Comment: Wouldn't it make a lot more sense to create a DirectoryInfo from the path?Are you even sure the path is correct? As for the error,it has nothing to do with Directory.Create. Post the *actual* code

Comment: try Directory.CreateDirectory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerPath"].ToString()) more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [`DirectoryInfo.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d869eykc.aspx) would throw an exception if it couldn’t create the directory, so it’s very likely that what you are doing *afterwards* is the actual problem here.

Comment: BTW you are using the wrong slash character. Even if  you used the correct one, you *CAN'T* write inside `wwwroot` without elevated permissions. Otherwise, any hacker could post malware inside the site's root folder

Comment: The proper way to find the site's folder is with [Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx), eg `Server.MapPath("/UploadFolder")` will return the proper path for a folder, `Server.MapPath("/UploadFolder/SomeFile.txt")` will return the relative path for a file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Windows does not actually care *that* much about using backslash characters for path separation.

Comment: @poke it cares about web site folders, a lot. Especially since the OP is trying to write directly in the server's root path. There are a lot of bugs in this code, the slashes are just one of them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I’m just saying that it doesn’t matter at all for a `DirectoryInfo` object whether paths are separate by back- or forward slashes.

Comment: There is no problem with the privileges, and I cant use Server.MapPath because I want to write to physical directory fetched from web.config

Comment: I see a lot of unclarity in this question and its comments, without any improvements being made by OP. Yet, there is only a single close vote on this question (mine). Can we please get this closed for now to avoid guess-answers?

Comment: @poke DirectoryInfo.Create() did the trick. If you want post it as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string serverPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerPath"].ToString();

new FileInfo(serverPath + "/" + file.Id).Directory.Create();
```

The problem with this approach is that you first create a [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) object and then access the directory of it using the [`Directory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directory.aspx) property.

In your case, your FileInfo object points to the file `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/103`. Note that I said **file**. The parent directory of that file is `C:/inetpub/wwwroot` which is then the `DirectoryInfo` object you call [`Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d869eykc.aspx) on.

Since the `wwwroot` folder obviously already exists, nothing is actually done. But the subdirectory `103` you actually wanted to create isn’t created as well.

To solve this, you need to interpret the `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/103` path *as a directory* in the first place. You can do that by simply creating a `DirectoryInfo` object directly:

```
new DirectoryInfo(serverPath + "/" + file.Id).Create();
```

Since you are actually doing something with a file `filename.png` in that folder, it might be a better idea however to go the opposite direction and start with that file and its FileInfo:

```
var file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(serverPath, file.Id, "filename.png"));

// create directory of that file; this does nothing if it already exists
file.Directory.Create();

// write to the file path, etc.
// …
```